# Why is my compare function not working for the highest input value and lowest input value?

Tags: java

Ok friends, I am trying to figure out why "-1" (my exit value) is compared and becomes my lowest grade and why "100" is not my highest grade. I'm sure they are simple reasons, but I don't see them.

sample input and output is the following:

Welcome to Grader-ator!

Enter a grade from 0 to 100, or enter a negative number to quit.
100

Enter a grade from 0 to 100, or enter a negative number to quit.
90

Enter a grade from 0 to 100, or enter a negative number to quit.
80

Enter a grade from 0 to 100, or enter a negative number to quit.
70

Enter a grade from 0 to 100, or enter a negative number to quit.
-1

Total sum of grades: 340

Total Number of Grades is: 4

Number of A's: 2

Number of B's: 1

Number of C's: 1

Number of D's: 0

Number of F's: 0

Highest Grade: 90

Lowest Grade: -1

Average Grade: 85.0

***CODE STARTS HERE***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab7 
{

    /**
     * author: Nate Fuller
     * date: 9 Feb 17
     * This program takes in any number of grades and performs some calculations
     */

    public static int grade, totalNumOfGrades, totalSumOfGrades, highestGrade, lowestGrade,
    numberOf_As, numberOf_Bs, numberOf_Cs, numberOf_Ds, numberOf_Fs,
    oldGrade, newGrade;
    public static double averageGrade;
    static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Grader-ator!");
        System.out.println("Enter a grade from 0 to 100, " +
                "or enter a negative number to quit.");

        totalSumOfGrades = 0;

        grade = kb.nextInt();
        while(grade >= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a grade from 0 to 100, " +
                    "or enter a negative number to quit.");

            determineGrade();
        }
        printGrades();
    }

    public static void determineGrade()
    {
        //A
        if(grade >= 90 && grade <= 100)
        {
            numberOf_As++;
            increment();
            compare();
        }
        //B
        else if(grade >= 80 && grade <= 89)
        {
            numberOf_Bs++;
            increment();
            compare();
        }
        //C
        else if(grade >= 70 && grade <= 79)
        {
            numberOf_Cs++;
            increment();
            compare();
        }
        //D
        else if(grade >= 60 && grade <= 69)
        {
            numberOf_Ds++;
            increment();
            compare();
        }
        //F
        else if(grade >= 0 && grade <= 59)
        {
            numberOf_Fs++;
            increment();
            compare();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and 100.");
            grade = kb.nextInt(); 
        }

    }

    public static void increment()
    {
        totalNumOfGrades++;
        totalSumOfGrades += grade;
        grade = kb.nextInt();
    }

    public static void compare()
    {
        newGrade = grade;
        if(newGrade > oldGrade)
        {
            highestGrade = newGrade;
        }
        else if(newGrade <= oldGrade)
        {
            lowestGrade = newGrade;
        }
        oldGrade = newGrade;
    }

    public static void printGrades()
    {
        //Calculations
        averageGrade = totalSumOfGrades/totalNumOfGrades;

        System.out.println("Total sum of grades: " + totalSumOfGrades);
        System.out.println("Total Number of Grades is: " + totalNumOfGrades);
        System.out.println("Number of A's: " + numberOf_As);
        System.out.println("Number of B's: " + numberOf_Bs);
        System.out.println("Number of C's: " + numberOf_Cs);
        System.out.println("Number of D's: " + numberOf_Ds);
        System.out.println("Number of F's: " + numberOf_Fs);
        System.out.println("Highest Grade: " + highestGrade);
        System.out.println("Lowest Grade: " + lowestGrade);
        System.out.println("Average Grade: " + averageGrade);
    }
}
```

Comment: See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You have a side effect in `increment()` that is likely the cause of all of your problems.

Comment: Correct, `increment()` will set `grade` to a new value, and this new value will be used in `compare()`, where you likely have mistaken that you're still using the old value.

Comment: The reason your highest grade isn't working is because your condition `if(newGrade > oldGrade)` is incorrect. `oldGrade` represents only the last grade. To get the highest grade, you must compare against the current highest grade, i.e. `if(newGrade > highestGrade)`.

Answer (score 0):

The whole if else block should be executed only if the newGrade is greater than equals 0. Added an if condition above all. This should solve the problem.

```
public static void compare()
{
   if(newGrade >=0 ) {
    newGrade = grade;
    if(newGrade > oldGrade)
    {
        highestGrade = newGrade;
    }
    else if(newGrade <= oldGrade)
    {
        lowestGrade = newGrade;
    }
    oldGrade = newGrade;
}
}
```

Comment: While this might work, it only further complicates his code by adding another edge case. Better to refactor the flow so that this isn't needed at all.

Comment: Yes, but we are not sure what is his broader use case. Also, as he knows where the issue is in the code, I believe he will be able to refactor it now.

Answer (score 0):

To make your program work, remove the line  `grade = kb.nextInt();` from `increment()` method and last `else` block in `determineGrade()` method.

In your main method, make the following change:

```
grade = 0;
while(grade >= 0)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a grade from 0 to 100, " + 
               "or enter a negative number to quit.");
     grade = kb.nextInt();
     determineGrade();
}
printGrades();
```

The reason why your code is not behaving accordingly is because before processing the input grade, you fetch the new input from the user and loose the old value which you needed for further processing.

Comment: Thank you! All of this worked, but my lowest value is now 0!

Comment: In your compare() method, remove the else if statement, instead only use if. Also, in your lowestGrade declaration statement, initialize lowestGrade to Integer.MAX_VALUE